# .htaccess rewrite rule redirect all from subfolder to another folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my .htaccess rules. I have the following scenario: before changes in my root I had a folder named "eleague" and everything worked fine. Now I have another folder (in the root) named "competitions" and a .htaccess(in root) file where I wrote some rules, something like these:

```
RewriteRule ^aleague/(.*)-(\d+).html.*$                 /competitions/competition.php?t_id=$2&text=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^bleague/(.*)-(\d+).html.*$                 /competitions/competition.php?t_id=$2&text=$1  [L]
...
RewriteRule ^eleague/(.*)-(\d+).html.*$                 /competitions/competition.php?t_id=$2&text=$1 [L]
```

What I want now is to modify .htaccess file from "eleague" folder to redirect all requests to my new location (last rule above to be matched). The trick is that I cannot (It`s a must!!) REMOVE the "eleague" folder from my directory structure.

Comment: And what is your problem? The rule should work as it is.

Comment: My old url`s still linking to old folder ("eleague") and are not redirected to "competitions"

Comment: Is that all, don't you have a `RewriteEngine on` for example? What's the reason not to include the whole .htaccess file in the question along with some incoming URL examples, to understand what are those rules trying to do? Only the rules don't help much as they don't work in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the new URL in the browser's bar, you must add a [redirect `R` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) to your rule

```
RewriteRule ^eleague/(.*)-(\d+).html.*$ /competitions/competition.php?t_id=$2&text=$1 [R,L]
```